# Better way to hide and show content when ready in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, show-hide

I'm thinking about creating a project where the users will only be shown a portion of the page when they meet certain requirements.

But how can I hide and show the content without using jQuery's .hide()/.show() or display
:none in css, as these can easily be unveiled by simply going into the code and making an easy change.

There must be a better way of doing this, any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Why hide anything at all? Users can just hit up dev tools and remove your hiding CSS, now you're back to "my users can see things I don't want them to see": if you don't want your users to see things they shouldn't, _don't have it on the page_, make the server generate content based on what the user should see. And if they log in, just reload the page so the server generates them the new (expanded) content.

Comment: This is usually done at the web server while rendering the page based on some criteria like user permissions.  The hidden sections are not included in the page.

Comment: Thank you guys! i will look into making the server generate the content when ready